# Scikit Learn :Multiple Fits

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

```
reg = linear_model.Ridge(alpha = 1.0)
reg.fit(x_train_1,y_train_1)
reg.fit(x_train_2,y_train_2)
```

When Scikit runs fitting does it maintain previous weights? If I implement something as shown above. From reading other regressions it seems that there's a attribute called "warm start" to keep previous weights/fit for SGDRegressor but ridge model lacks this feature.

Comment: Have you found the answer? I wish to know this too.